# Asynchronous execution in Matlab

Tags: multithreading, matlab

The bottleneck of my Matlab code looks like this:

```
x = randn(10^4,1);
y = CustomFunction(x) + CustomFunction(x+0.5);
```

Each call to `CustomFunction(x)` consumes about 0.1 seconds. As you can see, both evaluations are independent from each other and in theory could be run in parallel. Is it possible to implement this operation in parallel and gain speed by using multithreads, multicores or GPU?
Thanks!

Comment: hmmm, how do you know matlab is not already running it in parallel?

Comment: Take a look at the [parallel computation toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parfeval.html).

Comment: I have just tried parfeval and it is about 10x with respect to single core execution, for the size of the problem that I am dealing with.